# IIS 7.5 and handler mapping

Tags: iis-7, routes, handler

I want to redirect all urls like http://domain.com/xxx/yyyyy.html to my ASP.NET MVC application. I opened Handler Mappings for my site and added the following rule:

[image]

in web.config it look like:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
            <add name="HTML Rewriter" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

in routes of asp.net mvc application:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "xxx", // Route name
        "{ext}/{filename}.html", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Mycontr", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

but when I try to open this url I got 404 file not found. Why? It works locally under IIS express

Answer (score 0):

After adding handler you must have to execute it...

Goto edit feature setting...select execute option...

and also add this handler to ISAPI & CGI restrictions at server level..it will resolve the issue